# Nextjs api resolving before form.parse completes so i cant send response back

Tags: image, api, next.js, formidable

I am trying to send an image to Next.js api and then use that image to upload to db.

I am using :

```
const body = new FormData();
  body.append("file", prewiedPP);

  const response = await fetch("/api/send-pp-to-server", {
    method: "POST",
    body ,
    headers: {
           iext: iExt, 
           name: cCtx.userDetail ,
          },
  });
```

Then in the api :

```
    async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {

    console.log("In");

    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
     form.parse(req, 
        async (err, fields, files)  => 
     {
      //  console.log(req.headers.iext);
      //  console.log(req.headers.name);

       const fdata =  fs.readFileSync(files.file.filepath);

       await delUserPP(req.headers.name , req.headers.iext);

       await setUserPP(
          fdata , 
          req.headers.name , 
          req.headers.iext , 
          files.file.mimetype
        );

        fs.unlinkSync(files.file.filepath);

        return;
     });

     
    
     console.log("out");

  
 }
}

export default handler;
```

The callback function in the from.parse happens after the handler already resolved.

Is there anyway to make the api call only resolve after the `setUserPP` function is done?

I want to send a response back to the client but the api script finishes to "fast" and before the callback in form.parse runs.

Thanks

Comment: Promisify the form parsing and await the promise to resolve before returning from the API route.

Comment: The code snippets are badly formatted. You should at least use the code block
```javascript
```
which are less prone to formatting errors and add syntax highlighting.
Your question will be much more easy to read.